# how to install a plugin in elasticsearch

Tags: maven, elasticsearch

i have downloaded the zip package for hello world plugin from https://github.com/brusic/elasticsearch-hello-world-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugin/helloworld/HelloWorldPlugin.java

and have installed maven also but i want to know where to unzip this package and which command will be used to install and run it.I am working on windows so please provide a stepwise procedure according to it.please help

Comment: The commands to install the plugin are in the project's README: https://github.com/brusic/elasticsearch-hello-world-plugin/

Comment: i followed the same procedure but the last command is not working.Do i need to specify any url or the same command?

Comment: OK try and do it manually, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the project from github, build it, place the jar from the directory

```
elasticsearch-hello-world-plugin/target
```

Into the lib folder in Elastcsearch

```
elasticsearch/lib
```

Restart Elasticsearch